# How to execute multiple django celery tasks with a single worker?

Tags: django, multithreading, concurrency, celery, django-celery

Here is my celery file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ets.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('proj',

             broker='redis://myredishost:6379/0',
             backend='redis://myredishost:6379/0',
             include=['tracking.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Here is my task file:

```
@app.task
def escalate_to_sup(id, group):
    escalation_email, created = EscalationEmail.objects.get_or_create()
    escalation_email.send()

    return 'sup email sent to: '+str(group)


@app.task
def escalate_to_fm(id, group):
    escalation_email, created = EscalationEmail.objects.get_or_create()
    escalation_email.send()

    return 'fm email sent to: '+str(group)
```

I start the worker like this:

```
celery -A ets worker -l info
```

I have also tried to add concurrency like this:

```
celery -A ets worker -l info --concurrency=10
```

I attempt to call the tasks above with the following:

```
from tracking.tasks import escalate_to_fm, escalate_to_sup

    def status_change(equipment):
            r1 = escalate_to_sup.apply_async((equipment.id, [1,2]), countdown=10)
            r2 = escalate_to_fm.apply_async((equipment.id, [3,4]), countdown=20)

            print r1.id
            print r2.id
```

This prints:

> c2098768-61fb-41a7-80a2-f79a73570966
>   23959fa3-7f80-4e20-a42f-eef75e9bedeb

The escalate_to_sup and escalate_fm functions log to the worker intermittently.  At least 1 executes, but never both.

I have tried spinning up more workers, and then both tasks execute.  I do this like:

```
celery -A ets worker -l info --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h
celery -A ets worker -l info --concurrency=10 -n worker2.%h
```

The problem is I don't know how many of the tasks might execute concurrently so spinning up a worker for every possible tasks to execute is not feasible.

**Does celery expect a work for every active task?**

**How do I execute multiple tasks with a single worker?**